# Sort a while loop using exploded variable

Tags: php, sorting

I have got the following, but in the results is a long string, contained within that string is a server name which I am wanting to sort the results by, is this possible?

```
    <?php
$dbQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM opencall where cust_id = 'user.name@jpress' and status < 6  order by fixbyx asc") or die(mysql_error());//find call ref of open call with correct id
    while ($PRTGdbresults = mysql_fetch_array($dbQuery)){
    $SplitText = explode("\n", $probtext); //split the string by line break
    echo'<div class="row">';
    echo'<div class="inf_div" title="Current Server">';
            echo $SplitText[1]; //this is the server name I wish to sort by
        echo'</div></div>';
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own function for sorting and then use this function with the [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) sorting function.

Using the code you gave I will simply compare the strings of the server names and sort them in alphabetical order. Here is the code;

```
<?php
    $dbQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM opencall where cust_id = 'user.name@jpress' and status < 6  order by fixbyx asc") or die(mysql_error());
    $results = array();

    while ($PRTGdbresults = mysql_fetch_array($dbQuery)){
        array_push($results,$probtext);
    }

    usort($results, "sortProbtext");

    foreach($results as $key => $probtext){
        $SplitText = explode("\n", $probtext);
        echo'<div class="row">';
        echo'<div class="inf_div" title="Current Server">';
        echo $SplitText[1];
        echo'</div></div>';   
    }

    function sortProbtext($a, $b){
       $SplitTextA = explode("\n", $a);
       $SplitTextB = explode("\n", $b);
       if ($SplitTextA[1]  == $SplitTextB[1] ) {
          return 0;
       }
       return ($SplitTextA[1]  < $SplitTextB[1] ) ? -1 : 1;
    }
?>
```